# Why is css3 :target not working?

Tags: html, css

I have a div and I want that on click an other div slides in. I want to achieve this with css3 :target.

Like you can see in the code snippet the :hover works. When hovered an animation start to fade some info in. When you click on the image I want that an other div fades in on the top by calling the same animations as used on hover.

Can somebody help with getting the :target working?

```css
body{
 margin: 0px;
}
.image{
 position: relative;
 width:300px;
 height:auto;
}
.image img{
 width:100%;
}
.download{
 position: absolute;
 top:0px;
 left:0px;
 height:80%;
 width:100%;
 background-color: gray;
 display:none;
}
.info{
 position: absolute;
 bottom:0px;
 left:0px;
 height:20%;
 width:100%;
 background-color: green;
 opacity: 0;
 
}
.info p{
 padding: 5px;
 margin: 0px;
}

.image:hover .info{
 -webkit-animation: show 0.5s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: show 0.5s;
    opacity: 1;
}

.image:target .download{
 -webkit-animation: show 0.5s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: show 0.5s;
    opacity: 1;
}
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes show {
 from {opacity: 0;}
 to {opacity: 1;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes show {
 from {opacity: 0;}
 to {opacity: 1;}
}
```

```html
<div class="image"><!-- I detect everything on this div-->
 <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-gaBTIWFTWOo/UTeneLuwWyI/AAAAAAAABJE/E1GQBY4TJ8k/s1600/post-apocalypse-new-york.jpg">
 <div class="download"><!-- this div should fade in on click (:target)-->
  download
 </div>

 <div class="info"> <!-- this div should fade in on hover-->
  <p>Image 1</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Judging by your use of the word "click", you're probably confusing `:target` for `:active`. But swapping it alone doesn't change anything, so something else is wrong.

Comment: @BoltClock Can you explain the difference between :target and :active?

Comment: `:target` matches an element whose ID is equal to the URL hash. So if the hash on the URL is `#foo`, then `id="foo"` is `:target`. It has nothing to do with user interaction aside from clicking an anchor that points to that hash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved via jquery: http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/13/

```
$('.image').on('click', function(){
    $(this).find('.download').fadeIn(500);
});
```

i know you want to achieve this with :target, but you can do both animations through jquery to keep consistent if you would like. just another option...

Comment: I know how to do it in Jquery, but I think this is the only way to achieve what I want in my situation.

Comment: @Vinc199789 i think i got it in my other answer, the way you intended it to be...note: i think jquery option is better because :target requires id's so if you have multiple of these types of elements on the screen, it could get messy, whereas jquery you can use classes

Answer (score 0):

i think i got it the way you wanted with css:

added anchor tag surrounding image, added id #dl to download div...heres the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/14/

```
:target {
    display:block;
    -webkit-animation: show 0.5s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera*/
    animation: show 0.5s;
    opacity: 1;
} 

<div class="image"><!-- I detect everything on this div-->
    <a href="#dl">
    <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-gaBTIWFTWOo/UTeneLuwWyI/AAAAAAAABJE/E1GQBY4TJ8k/s1600/post-apocalypse-new-york.jpg"/>
    <div class="download" id="dl"><!-- this div should fade in on click (:target)-->
        download
    </div>

    <div class="info"> <!-- this div should fade in on hover-->
        <p>Image 1</p>
    </div>
    </a>
</div>
```